# Check memory usage in haskell

Tags: haskell, caching, memory, memory-management, resources

I'm creating a program which implements some kind of cache. I need to use as much memory as possible and to do that I need to do two things:

1. Check how much memory is still available in system (RAM only, not SWAP)
2. Check how much memory my app is already using.

I need a platform independent solution (Linux, Windows, etc.).

Using these two pieces of information I will reduce the size of cache or enlarge it. 
How can I get this information in Haskell? Are there any packages that can provide that information?

Comment: "Check how much memory is still available in system". This question doesn't have a lot of sense. You have a swap file that can grow up to 2TB. Is all that memory "available"? If you occupy it all, your system will grind to a halt. Perhaps you want to check physical memory. But what if you have 300 tabs open in a browser that are all sitting untouched for a week? They are ready to be swapped out at a drop of a hat, but they are occupying 99.5% of physical memory right now, so you have nothing at all "available".

Comment: @n.m. I think that's obvious that to implement cache I need amount of free space that is in RAM, not in SWAP. Building a cache that will make system swapping isn't a good idea. ;p

Comment: Why not let the user specify the cache size?  They may not want a program that automatically uses all the RAM anyway.

Comment: @JohnL I want user to specify cache size, but if they don't do that, default is maximum available.

Comment: @remdezx I agree with n-m here. On my machine (a Mac) you'd probably get zero or nearly zero available RAM all the time. I haven't switched it off for weeks and I haven't closed an application for months (if I reboot, the mac reloads, on login, all applications that were open when I logged off/shut it down). All 8GB of ram are always fully used (especially if you include disk caching). Memory is allocated/freed on demand. Memory used by lingering (inactive) applications gets compressed first and then eventually swapped off on demand. Just use a sensible size (maybe configurable).

Comment: To expand @AnalogFile comment: OS X has RAM split into free, wired, active, and inactive memory. Details here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1342 . Short version: free is free, inactive are leftovers that are not removed as long as possible (for quicker start of applications), active is used by currently running programs, wired is OS X reserved.

Comment: @AnalogFile, if Mac separates between free, inactive and non-free memory it is possible to get somehow that information. As I see, this solution will be very platform specific and will require to do it another way on Windows, Mac, etc. 
So there is still another part of my question, what is the easier platform independent way to check how much memory my app is already using?

Comment: @remdezx there are APIs to do that. I'm not sure what they are but there surely are as there are programs that display that information. However it will not be useful to you. Here's what my mac currently reports (I have 4GB RAM): wired 1.36 GB, active 2.05 GB, inactive 551 MB, free 40 MB. The inactive one is due to the fact that yesterday I closed the iTunes application and three media (video) players (they had been open for more than 6 weeks, but I have not used any of them for the last 10 days) and the system has not yet re-used all that memory because I've not run any new application.

Answer (score 4):

I can't immediately see how to do this portably.

However, GHC does have "weak pointers". (See `System.Mem.Weak`.) If you create items and hang on to them via weak pointers (only), then *the garbage collector* will automatically start deleting items if you run low on physical memory.

(Unfortunately, this doesn't give you the ability to decide *which* items to delete first — e.g., the ones that are cheapest to recreate or the ones that have been least-used or something.)

Comment: Looks very interesting! Unfortunately, it will require some architecture change, but I can consider it. Thanks!

Comment: You may also be interested to know that `System.Mem` contains functions to provoke the GC to run at a specific time (e.g., after you just stopped using a really big object). Not directly related to your question, but might be interesting.

Comment: I know, I found them when I was digging more into that topic :)

Comment: I don't think this will work very well.  First, the garbage collector will free items when they're no longer referenced elsewhere.  They won't just hang around.  You'd have to completely disable automatic GC, which may not even be possible (and will surely be painful).  Second, the GHC RTS doesn't return allocated memory to the system, so even after items are freed the process will  hang on to the RAM.  It may get paged out, but given how GHC uses blocks I'd expect the process to start thrashing.